# ReactJS Updating display

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**Newbie** question.

I'm learning ReactJS in Typescript and am coming from an AngularJS background (trying to unlearn AngularJS).

The code below runs and displays the `props.compiler`. When I tap the `H1`, the `handler` fires but the React code doesn't update the display like it would in `AngularJS`.

What am I missing?

```
export interface IHelloProps {
  compiler: string;
  framework: string;
}

export class Hello extends React.Component<IHelloProps> {
  constructor(props: IHelloProps) {
    super(props);
    this.x = props.compiler;
  }

  private x: string;

  get Name(): string {
    return this.x;
  }

  set Name(value: string) {
    this.x = value;
  }

  render() {
    return <h1 onClick={this.handler}>Hello from {this.Name}!</h1>;
  }

  handler = async (t: any) => {
    const resp = await fetch('https://api.github.com');
    const data = await resp.json();
    this.Name = data.current_user_url;
  };
}
```

Comment: is there any error or just the display won't update.. did you try to ```console.log(props.compiler)``` data ? what's coming ? there's a concept called state, you need to add this.state in constructor, and when you apply ```this.setState``` inside this.handler function , it will re-render you component , thus updating display

Comment: You should store the `name` variable in the `state` and then use `setState` to change its value. This is the React away and will trigger a component rerendering not using getters and setters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no [two-way binding like in AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_06), you need to use [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) in [order to schedule an update](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-does-setstate-do) to a component’s state object:

```
// A bit more React-Class oriented example
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentUser: this.props.compiler
  };

  handler = async t => {
    const resp = await fetch('https://api.github.com');
    const data = await resp.json();
    this.setState({ currentUser: data.current_user_url });
  };

  render = () => {
    const { currentUser } = this.state;
    return <h1 onClick={this.handler}>Hello from {currentUser}!</h1>;
  };
}
```

```
// Original OP class
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      x: props.compiler
    };
  }

  get Name() {
    return this.state.x;
  }
  set Name(value) {
    this.setState({ x: value });
  }

  handler = async t => {
    const resp = await fetch('https://api.github.com');
    const data = await resp.json();
    this.setState({ x: data.current_user_url });
  };

  render = () => {
    return <h1 onClick={this.handler}>Hello from {this.Name}!</h1>;
  };
}
```

Try reading the [Getting Started](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) section which explains it in depth.

[image: Edit Q-58595576-BasicState]

Comment: ah, so the trick is the state and setState. I think AngularJS has some magic that I need to handle myself in ReactJS.

Comment: AngularJs does it internally by setting up watchers on the bindings or the directive you use and as soon the value gets dirty it triggers an update event and updates the value :)

Answer (score 2):

In React you don't set the values like you did in your setter function.

React renders the DOM asynchronously by comparing the virtual DOM.

So you need to use setState() to update the state of your DOM.

You can add state in your code and pass it to the React component.

```
handler = async (t: any)=> {
  const resp = await fetch('https://api.github.com');
  const data = await resp.json();
  this.Name=data.current_user_url;
  this.setState({name:data.current_user_url}); //name being the state variable
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: setState and state are the keys to the data flow. thanks.

Comment: Yes correct. That's why I directly provided a hint to your handler function where all magic will happen. Infact setState() takes a callback function also as setState() runs asynchronously and React doesn't guarantee you that your updated state will reflect immediately. So sometimes you need to make use of that callback function also. Good luck with learning React. I am here to always help :)

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript's interface is purely for typechecking. You should not be directly referencing any of its properties.

Instead, I would recommend you to create an interface for your state, which holds the values of `current_user_url` from your `fetch` request.

Then, on your click handler, you update the state by calling [setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to re-render the component with the updated state. On important thing to take note, is that you should [never mutate state directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly).

In order to fully implement TypeScript's typechecking capabilities on your component, you should use provide `React.Component` with its prop and state type parameters.

I have modified your code such that your component is TypeScript-compliant. Do take note of the new `IHelloState` interface.

```
export interface IHelloProps { 
  compiler: string; 
  framework: string; 
}

export interface IHelloState { 
  name: string; 
}

export class Hello extends React.Component<IHelloProps, IHelloState> {

  constructor(props: IHelloProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
    };
  }


  handler = async (t: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>)=> {
    const resp = await fetch('https://api.github.com');
    const data = await resp.json();
    this.setState({
      name: data.current_user_url,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { name } = this.state;

    return <h1 onClick={this.handler}>
             Hello from {name}
        </h1>;
  }

}
```

You may read more about working with React and TypeScript over [here](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet).

Comment: So the setState and the state is where the values flow. I'll go read up on that.

Comment: @IanVink Bingo! In addition, you should read up about TypeScript (as well as how you can use that with React), and the way interfaces (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) are being used.

Comment: @IanVink just made some changes on my code as I have made some errors to my interfaces. In addition, I have added proper typings for the click event handler. It is actually bad practice to use `any`.